# Does GetListItems not work with content types?

Tags: content-type, jquery, spservices, site-column

I have been trying to use GetListItems using jquery and SOAP to fetch data from a list. The list does not have an 'item' content type but is using two other site content types (both inherited from 'item' and having different site columns). None of the fields that are a part of the site content types are appearing in the result.

I switched to SPServices 2014-1 by Marc but even that is showing the site columns as undefined.(SPServices anyways calls getlistitems so I just completed a circle).

My question is: Do content type specific columns not work with getlistitems?

UPDATE: Apparently, it appears to be an issue with CAMLViewFields. I changed the SOAP request to query all fields by removing the CAMLViewFields option. Now I'm getting the four useful site columns besides the 25 that are not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the question needed to be more clear. I could not find certain fields while using jquery ajax to call the lists.asmx and call GetListItems. Apparently, by default, the call fetches fields that are present in the default view of the list.

To answer the question: Simply add the fields needed to the default view (AllItems.aspx, in most cases) of the list on which GetListItems is to be run.